# plotting: color based on the combination of two column levels

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

How to plot based on the combination of two column levels(here: `treatment`, `replicate`)?

```
set.seed(0)
x <- rep(1:10, 4)
y <- sample(c(rep(1:10, 2)+rnorm(20)/5, rep(6:15, 2) + rnorm(20)/5))
treatment <- sample(gl(8, 5, 40, labels=letters[1:8]))
replicate <- sample(gl(8, 5, 40))
d <- data.frame(x=x, y=y, treatment=treatment, replicate=replicate)
```

plots: color based on single column levels

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=treatment)) + geom_point()
```

[image: output]

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=replicate)) + geom_point()
```

[image: output]

The combination of two column levels would be `a-1, a-2, a-3, ... h-6, h-7, h-8`.

Comment: What about just concatenate two variables?

Comment: W/ 8x8, there will be 64 possible combinations? Is that what you want?

Comment: @gung yes, exactly

Comment: @amatsuo_net Thanks for the nice suggestion, But I want to do it in runtime without creating new variables unless there is no other chance possible.

Comment: `colour=interaction(treatment,replicate, sep="-")`.

Comment: @eipi10 Excellent suggestion. Could you please add it as an answer, I will accept it :)

Comment: @Prradep Not sure why you don't like amatsuo's suggestion but you do like eipi's... replace `interaction` with `paste` for the same result.

Comment: @Gregor I have no specific inclination towards any of the above answers. Any answer which can be incorporated in ggplot would be useful. Now, both are useful approaches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

64 colours will be uninterpretable. How about point labels instead:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=treatment)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=paste0(treatment, replicate)), size=3, show.legend=FALSE) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Or, if you're trying to spot differences in patterns for different treatments, maybe faceting would help:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=treatment)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=paste0(treatment, replicate)), size=3, show.legend=FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~ treatment, ncol=4) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0.7)) +
  theme_bw() + theme(panel.grid=element_blank())
```

[image]

But, if you really want a whole bunch of colours...

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=interaction(treatment,replicate,sep="-",lex.order=TRUE))) + 
  geom_point() +
  labs(colour="Treatment-Replicate") +
  theme_classic()
```

(If you want all potential `treatment-replicate` combinations to be listed in the legend, regardless of whether they're present in the data, then add `+ scale_colour_discrete(drop=FALSE)` to the plot code.)

[image]

Comment: Thanks @eipi10 for your educative examples. I was looking for the last example in the current scenario and would be very interesting to use the other two types of plotting.